# Not able to export russian or turkish characters to csv from asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am exporting the data into csv from asp.net mvc controller using the File method like below. It works fine for english,french but not working for some other languages likes russian,turkish. Any thoughts or help will be much helpful.

```
var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(csv);
var finalData = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding().GetPreamble()
                    .Concat(bytes).ToArray();
ActionResult result = this.File(finalData, "text/x-csv", filename);
```

Comment: `but not working` means? Any error?

Comment: it's showing junk characters instead of russian characters.

Comment: Any solution ? I am also facing the same issue for Turkish Language.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with encoding, try something like this:

```
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes();
```

In combination with this resource: 
https://www.terena.org/activities/multiling/ml-docs/iso-8859.html

Comment: I tried the above way, it sending the data but text is getting changed into some other characters.

Comment: Yes..its not exporting into csv as expected. Characters are getting changes in csv excel.